# Web deployment task failed in web deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having an issue with deploying my website to my domain.

It was online but was duplicating entries in DataBase with Entity Framework, I removed to re-allocate offline Website but when I deploy is bugging.

I tried to clean solution and rebuilding but it's not working. It throws an exception on deploying:

> Web deployment task failed. (Unknown ProviderOption:DefiningProjectFullPath. Known ProviderOptions are:skipInvalid.)

[image: Deployment error message in Visual Studio]

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem on our build servers.
Visual Studio 2013 Premium Update 1 was installed there.

After I've **upgraded to VS 2013 Update 2 RC** everything worked as before. It comes with a go-live license and you'll be able to update to the RTM, when it's released.

I've got the hint in this comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/04/02/tfs-2013-2-update-2-released.aspx#10515773