# Web deployment task failed. (Unknown ProviderOption:DefiningProjectFullPath. Known ProviderOptions are:skipInvalid.)

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2013

I tried to publish a web project from Visual Studio 2013 but kept getting this error using web deploy.

Web deployment task failed. Unknown ProviderOption: DefiningProjectFullPath. Known ProviderOptions are:skipInvalid.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21849681/web-deployment-task-failed-in-web-deployment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same error.

I got this error after installing TFS RM Update2.
What you need to do is replace the contents of "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web" on your build server with the contents of that same folder on your development pc.

This worked for me anyways.

Comment: What if the deploying machine is the development one??

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue after installing update 4 for Visual Studio 2013.

**Solution:**
Install the Visual Studio update on the build server.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue when I updated my Build server to compile using new roslyn compiler (to use c# 6 features) and after installing [required stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32070490/how-to-build-net-4-6-framework-app-without-visual-studio-installed) (The .NET 4.6 Framework, The Microsoft Build Tools 2015, The .NET Framework 4.6 targeting Pack) I got error on missing *`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets`* when I tried to publish project (`"Package"` Msbuild target).

So I added `/p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0` parameter MSBuild command that do publishing so the target from *`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets`* would be taken and then I got the error in question (`Web deployment task failed. (Unknown ProviderOption:DefiningProjectFullPath. Known ProviderOptions are:skipInvalid.)`)

I got two solutions for this problem:

1. Copy `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets` from you local machine to build server and remove `/p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0` parameter from MSBuild command argumens. The the new MSBuild (located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe'`) would by default set `VisualStudioVersion` as `14.0` and would use the new MSBuild target that works with new compiler.
2. If you don't have access to build server then install [MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets) NuGet package (you need to install it to at least one project in solution) and then remove this `/p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0` command argument from MSBuild and add below text to .csproj file of project that can't be published:

```xml
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != '' And Exists('$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets')" />
<Import Project="..\..\packages\MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets.14.0.0\tools\VSToolsPath\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="('$(VSToolsPath)' == '' Or !Exists('$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets')) And Exists('..\..\packages\MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets.14.0.0\tools\VSToolsPath\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets')" />
```

This will first check if you have `Microsoft.WebApplication.targets` on build server (in `...VisualStudio\v14.0\` directory) and if not it will import the one from solution (included in `packages` directory)

If it won't work check if you have this in your .csproj file:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>    
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: What if the deploying machine is the development one??

Answer (score 1):

Inside Visual Studio go to Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Updates -> Product Updates

Install the latest Azure SDK (**even if you are not using Azure**).

[Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d26da0d5-c9d6-4557-b792-4d610714f54b/web-publish-fails-unknown-provideroptiondefiningprojectfullpath?forum=msbuild)

Also, I had this [MSBuild Targets NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets) installed which was for VS2012 targets. I installed the version for my version of VS (2013) and everything was back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I have Visual Studio 2013 but yesterday I installed also Visual Studio 2015, and give me the same error when try to publish a site in VS 2013.. I solved this just run update 5 of visual studio 2013

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue in VS 2013 after I installed the 2015 preview.

My solution is to publish from VS 2015 only...