# How to build .NET 4.6 Framework app without Visual Studio installed?

Tags: msbuild, .net-4.6

Until now, I could build .NET 4.5.2 using command line

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild MySolution.sln
```

The only what I need to install on a computer was .NET Framework and [Visual Studio 2010 shell](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1366).

Now I consider upgrading to .NET 4.6., but I cannot find a way how to build a solution without Visual Studio.

I don't want to install Visual Studio 2015, because it is too big for this hosted virtual machine. I hope some MSBuild or Microsoft package installation could be sufficient.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Install:

- The [.NET 4.6 Framework](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=528259)
- The [Microsoft Build Tools 2015](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159)
- The [.NET Framework 4.6 targeting Pack](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=528261)

Then call a different version of MsBuild to build your solution:

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MsBuild.exe MySolution.sln
```

Note, this may not contain all bits pieces and sdk's that ship with Visual Studio, so you may encounter "missing `.targets` files" or other problems building your application. Other SDKs may alleviate that problem:

- The [Windows 10 Platform SDK](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk)
- The [Azure SDK](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/)

Comment: After installing the above packeges I still getting error MSB4019. Hopefully I could solve it by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718281/external-vs2013-build-error-error-msb4019-the-imported-project-path-was-not

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? You may need additional SDK's to be installed, depending on what kind of app you're trying to build. Try building a simple Console App that does Hello World, that should work now.

Comment: @jessehouwig: And did you also installed Windows SDK because of x64 sgen as described here or do you build x86 app only? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373297/sgen-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-an-assembly-with-an-incorrect-format

Comment: I usually just install Visual Studio on my build servers :).

Comment: For me, build done successfully after installing .Net Framework and Build tools. The targeting pack was not necessary.

Comment: The new [Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017 RC](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017-rc) are making this requirement a thing of the past: if you can migrate your code to Visual Studio 2017 you will be able to use them.

Comment: This helped me to discover that the new project in my solution is using a higher framework's version of the rest of the projects that references it, and that why I got build/compile errors.

Comment: Reinstalling "Microsoft Build Tools 2015" solved the problem. Some home it was installed but MSBuild.exe was missing... Required for Jenkins builds.

Comment: This worked until  I came across a project that needs the SdkToolsPath.  It keeps looking in the registry under the NETFXSDK\4.6 key. I installed the 4.6.2 developer kit but that doesn't set the 4.6 key.  I try passing SdkToolsPath as a property to MSbuild but that doesn't work either.  How should I approach this?  I can't figure out where to download the 4.6 SDK.